# Why do i get an error cannot find symbol , symbol:class Mongoclient?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, mongotemplate

I am trying to create new collection in existing database.

```
try {
        
     MongoCollection collection = null;
     MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("127.0.0.1", 27017);
     MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(mongoClient, "udata");
     collection = mongoTemplate.createCollection("MyNewCollection");
     }
     catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
```

i am using spring boot and importing the following packages:

```
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients;

import com.oegems.ems.EmsMongoOps;

import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection ;
```

This is My pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.oegems</groupId>
    <artifactId>ems</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ems</name>
    <description>Demo project for ..</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Paste your `pom.xml`. No one can suggest a solution for your problem if they can't see what you have in your dependencies.

Comment: I have edited the question and added pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

Your import contains this:

`import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients;`

which is a valid class, a factory for `MongoClient` instances

**Mind the extra `s` in the end**

Then, you use:

`MongoClient mongoClient`

Note that the compiler has recognised `MongoCollection` from the line above which is the same package as `MongoClient`

So use one instead of the other:

`import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient;`

`import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients;`